# Android MediaCodec seems to be ignoring specified KEY_BIT_RATE value

Tags: android, video, media, codec

I need to implement H264 encoding and configure MediaCodec as follows

```
    MediaCodec codec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");
    MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", resolution.getWidth(), resolution.getHeight());

    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 1);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 1000000);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE,30);
    codec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
```

Bitrate is set to 1000000 and this is a requirement defined by network limitations. When I test on Samsung Galaxy J7 I see 1000 kbps in output as expected. But when I test the same code on some particular devices like Samsung Galaxy Grand 2 Duos (android 4.4) or Huawei Nexus 6P (android 7.1.2), I see that the encoder produces up to 5 megabytes per second in output, that means that specified value 1000000 bits per second is totally ignored by codec. What's wrong with it? Is there a way to force encoder to use this specified value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

True reason of this behavior was in timestamps that I transferred to the encoder when pushed frames in. On a developing stage for simplicity I used System.nanoTime() value as a timestamp. This timestamp expressed time in nanoseconds while encoder requires microseconds as a timestamp.

Most of codec implementations probably use their own timer to measure real incoming fps and thus they do not depend on a actual timestamp values and just ignore them. But Nexus 6P has probably a smart one, this encoder uses timestamps to measure fps value. Timestamps were given in nanoseconds and from the point of view of the codec time flow was 1000 times slower and measured fps was 1000/30 ~ 1 frame per 33 seconds and thus the codec tried to push all requested megabit into a single output frame.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem as well, it only happened on one device (Moto E Plus on 7, although the Moto E on 6 was fine, as were other devices on 7) and further testing revealed that it was using the assigned bitrate as Kbps instead of the specified bps. 
Unfortunately the only "solution" I've found to detecting android implementations that make this mistake is to watch the output from the media codec and reset it at bitrate/1000 if it looks like it's outputting too much data.

Comment: I think you also feed encoder with nanosecond timestamps and that's true reason of your issue. Nanosecond timestamps change unit of measure of framerate to frames per kilosecond. That means that you need to change unit of measure of bitrate to kilobits per second to keep measurement correctness and correct behavior. Thanks anyway, your answer pushed me to right idea.

Comment: I confirmed that I'm handing the codec microseconds, so I guess we were just looking at two different issues with similar symptoms. I won't rule out that I did something wrong - which is why I just double checked my timestamps - but for now I'm blaming the OEM for my issue. Glad your issue was easier to sort out.

Comment: I have run into same problem with moto c plus . I am sure microseconds is going in instead of nanoseconds . Not facing this problem with any other devices (15 something)  i tested with .